# How should I let my "fluent" work well?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a "fluent" on the emacs.

```
  CPL> (make-fluent :name 'fl :value 1)
  #<FLUENT FL [1]>
```

It seems working well. But....
when I give the command like below

```
  CPL> (wait-for (< fl 20))
```

The error message appear as below.

```
  The variable FL is unbound.
  [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]
```

How can I fix it? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47225/how-should-i-let-my-%22fluent%22-work-well?/) by [Jui Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/2167/jui-wang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While you created a fluent object you didn't bind it to a variable. Try:

```
(defvar fl (make-fluent :name 'fl :value 1))
```

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/cram_core/Tutorials/ControllingTurtlesimFromLisp) for a more sophisticated example that uses fluents.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2